# Changing font color on a column in treeview gtk

Tags: gtk, cellrenderer, gtktreeview

I've a treeview and I want to change the text color on one column.

How could I do this??

thanks

Comment: Actually I'm working on vala, but it doesn't matter. Any answer in any lenguage will be fine :)

Answer (score 2):

(Refering to the standard C methods, haven't done much with Vala so far)

There are several ways to achieve this. You can change the settings of the text cellrenderer (GtkCellRendererText), an example would be

```
g_object_set (your_text_cell_renderer, "foreground", 
              "red", "foreground-set", TRUE);
```

Another way is using markup:

```
highlighted_txt = g_strconcat ("<span background='yellow' foreground='black'>", 
                               my_text, "</span>", NULL);
g_object_set (your_text_cell_renderer, "markup", highlighted_txt, NULL);
```

To change the font color of each column individually on certain conditions, 
gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_data_func or gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func 
are used, they are described in the online documentation for GtkTreeView. You can use 
different text cell renderers for each column to keep settings separate.

It can be done in a way similar like this:

```
for (columns_cnt = 0; columns_cnt < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; columns_cnt++) {
  text_renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  columns[columns_cnt] = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes
                         (column_header_txt[columns_cnt], text_renderer, 
                         "text", columns_cnt, NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func (columns[columns_cnt], text_renderer, 
                                           (GtkTreeCellDataFunc) 
                                           set_column_attributes, NULL, NULL);
}

...

static void set_column_attributes (GtkTreeViewColumn *cell_column, 
                                   GtkCellRenderer   *txt_renderer,
                                   GtkTreeModel      *cell_model, 
                                   GtkTreeIter       *cell_iter, 
                                   gpointer          pointer)
{
 // Use g_object_set or something else here.
}
```

Comment: This will affect all rows, but on the other hand, OP didn't ask a very precise question.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added something about the cell data functions right now. And you can use different text renderers for each column, if you want to.

Comment: @matthias yes, it's not a precise question because I really don't know how it'll be :P

Comment: @MarcusSchaetzle This is great. to many option to play with. I'll check all of this. that markup is interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to set up a column in your model describing the color for each row. Then, you use [gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-insert-column-with-attributes), to set the `foreground` attribute to the position of the color column.